# lsass.exe and UDP port 53

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, lsass

We have DC and DNS on the same server (Windows Server 2012), but today I had seen that lsass.exe uses UDP :53 and our DNS server also requires this incomming UDP port to serve queries through UDP.

Is't possible to resolve this conflict between DNS and lsass.exe?

Comment: I've seen lsass.exe send outbound 53/udp packets, but never listening on that port. If you run tasklist /svc, which services are hosted in that lsass.exe process?

Comment: lsass.exe                      
Kdc, KeyIso, Netlogon, NTDS, SamSs, VaultSv

Comment: I'm not seeing this on my servers. Netstat shows dns.exe bound to port 53. Are you getting an error when you try to start the DNS Server service? If not, what happens when you try to query against the service?